# Why must I explicitly set a namespace for the ServiceAccount of ClusterRoleBinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io resource?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm deploying my chart with helm like this:

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace newnamespace --create-namespace testing mychart
```

My understanding is everything should be deployed into `newnamespace`

I have this in my chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services","endpoints","pods"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: ["extensions","networking.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["ingresses"] 
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
```

When deployed I get this error:

```
Error: ClusterRoleBinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "my-service-account" is invalid: subjects[0].namespace: Required value
```

Then I add this and the deploy works:

```
...
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
      namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

Why is this? What is this requirement of ClusterRoleBinding? I can't it see the namespace where it's being deployed?

Is it because ClusterRoleBinding is cluster wide it *must* have the namespace defined in its definition? Are ClusterRoleBinding resources not created in any namespaces? If so where do they live kube-system?

Does this mean that if I deleted the namespace containing my helm release before doing a helm uninstall the ClusterRoleBinding would be left behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClusterRoleBinding` binds the `ClusterRole` with you service account. `ClusterRoleBinding` gives the access in cluster-wide. In cluster role you basically tell that what actions can your service account perform. A ClusterRole is a set of permissions that can be assigned to resources within a given cluster.

Now by `ClusterRoleBinding` you are just binding the `ClusterRole` with your service account, as service account is a namespace scoped object so you must need to provide the namespace name in your subject as you did in the second part.

btw, `ClusterRole` is a non-namespaced resource. As far the k8s docs, you can use a `ClusterRole` to:

- define permissions on namespaced resources and be granted within individual namespace(s)
- define permissions on namespaced resources and be granted across all namespaces
- define permissions on cluster-scoped resources

Another thing will also work is adding the `apiGroup` like   `apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io`.

When you created `service account` you created in basically in `default` namespace as it is the default thing, here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
```

As your last question, `ClusterRole` is cluster-scoped but `ClusterRoleBinding` and `service account` is namespace scoped and as far the rules if you delete a namespace then all the object of that namespace will be gone along with the namespace.

You can see the k8s [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-binding-examples) for getting more clear idea.

I found another good [tuto](https://octopus.com/blog/k8s-rbac-roles-and-bindings)